# Cypress: copy paste shortcuts not working

Tags: cypress

I am testing a simple `<input type="text" />` element with Cypress.

When I run the following test:

```
it("should copy and paste", () => {
  cy.get("input")
    .type("hello {ctrl+a}{ctrl+c}{movetoend}{ctrl+v}{ctrl+v}")
    .should("have.value", "hello hello hello ");
});
```

I get the following assertion error:

> expected '<input>' to have value 'hello hello hello ', but the value was 'hello '

Comment: I may be missing some information. Wouldn't copy paste testing be testing an os system as opposed to a web application?

Comment: @jjhelguero Yes you are right, but in my case, my colleague wrote custom keyboard shortcuts for the input to accept which I am testing. However, I am having trouble testing a vanilla input element using Cypress as explained above.

Comment: I think shedding some light on the what the custom keyboard shortcuts may help. So far your example shows selecting all the text, which is `hello ` and then pasting it at the end twice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that {ctrl+c} is not copying the desired value to the clipboard.

For that you should look at this link: [Handling Copy and Paste in Cypress](https://egghead.io/blog/handling-copy-and-paste-in-cypress)